# C++ Help (ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.)

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make a very simple program with stacks but i seem to be getting an error when i try to run it. The error says "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.". Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int maxstack = 5;

struct stacktype{
    string name[maxstack];
    int top;
};

void createstack(stacktype &stack);
void destroystack(stacktype &stack);
bool fullstack(stacktype stack);
void push(stacktype &stack, string &newelement);
bool emptystack(stacktype stack);
void pop(stacktype &stack, string &poppedelement);

int main(){
    stacktype stack;
    string newelement, poppedelement;
    char quest;

    createstack(stack);
    cout<<"Do you want to enter data? (y/n)";
    cin>>quest;

    while((quest == "y" || quest == "Y") && !(fullstack(stack))){ //I get the error on this line
        cout<<"Please enter name";
        cin>>newelement;
        push(stack, newelement);
        cout<<"Do you want to enter data? (y/n)";
        cin>>quest;
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    while(!emptystack(stack)){
        pop(stack, poppedelement);
        cout<<poppedelement<<endl;
    }

    destroystack(stack);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void createstack(stacktype &stack){
    stack.top = -1;
}
void destroystack(stacktype &stack){
    stack.top = -1;;
}
bool fullstack(stacktype stack){
    if(stack.top == maxstack - 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
void push(stacktype &stack, string &newelement){
    stack.top++;
    stack.name[stack.top] = newelement;
}
bool emptystack(stacktype stack){
    if(stack.top == -1){    
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
void pop(stacktype &stack, string &poppedelement){
    poppedelement = stack.name[stack.top];
    stack.top--;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quest` is a `char`, yet `"y"` is a string literal with type `const char[2]`. When you try to compare these with `quest == "y"`, the string literal is converted to a pointer to its first element, and so you are attempting to compare a `char` with a pointer. That's what the error is telling you.

Instead of a string literal, you want a character literal like `'y'`, which has type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`quest` is of char type, so it is single character, and you try to compare it with string literals like `"y"`. Use single quotes for char literals: `'y'`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are writing C++ code, you should use the `string` class instead of `"y"`.

Comment: Is it April 1 already?